Whatsapp Flow not getting send to iOS devices but working fine in Android devices
I am not able to send WhatsApp flows to iOs devices but it is getting send easily to Android devices. I am getting status = 200 and I am not able to understand the issue with iOs? Someone please help me.
Not getting any error. Read the documentation but couldn't find anything to resolve the issue.
Flow json:
{
    "version":"3.1",
    "screens":[
        {
            "id":"RECOMMEND",
            "title":"Feedback 1 of 1",
            "data":{
                
            },
            "terminal":true,
            "success":true,
            "layout":{
                "type":"SingleColumnLayout",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "type":"Form",
                        "name":"form",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "type":"TextSubheading",
                                "text":"Give feedback?"
                            },
                            {
                                "type":"Dropdown",
                                "label":"Rate your experience",
                                "name":"demo_feedback",
                                "data-source":[
                                    {
                                        "id":"0",
                                        "title":"★★★★★ • Excellent (5/5)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id":"1",
                                        "title":"★★★★☆ • Good (4/5)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id":"2",
                                        "title":"★★★☆☆ • Average (3/5)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id":"3",
                                        "title":"★★☆☆☆ • Poor (2/5)"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id":"4",
                                        "title":"★☆☆☆☆ • Very Poor (1/5)"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "required":true
                            },
                            {
                                "type":"TextSubheading",
                                "text":"How could we do better?"
                            },
                            {
                                "type":"TextArea",
                                "label":"Leave a comment",
                                "required":false,
                                "name":"comment_text"
                            },
                            {
                                "type":"Footer",
                                "label":"Submit",
                                "on-click-action":{
                                    "name":"complete",
                                    "payload":{
                                        "demo_feedback":"${form.demo_feedback}",
                                        "comment_text":"${form.comment_text}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Message payload:
{
    "recipient_type":"individual",
    "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
    "to":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_PHONE_NUMBER",
    "type":"interactive",
    "interactive":{
        "type":"flow",
        "body":{
            "text":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_FLOW_BODY"
        },
        "footer":{
            "text":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_FLOW_FOOTER"
        },
        "action":{
            "name":"flow",
            "parameters":{
                "mode":"published",
                "flow_message_version":"3",
                "flow_token":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_USER_IDENTIFIER",
                "flow_id":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_FLOW_ID",
                "flow_cta":"TEXT_SHOWN_ON_FLOW_BUTTON",
                "flow_action":"navigate",
                "flow_action_payload":{
                    "screen":"TOBE_FILLED_WITH_FIRST_SCREEN_ID"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried meta documentation, I also posted same query on Meta community.

Can you please specify a few things to help identify the issue


What do you see on iOS device exactly?


What version of WhatsApp for iOS are you using?


Is the iOS device a primary device? or is it linked as a secondary device via QR code? Secondary devices do not support Flows at the moment



I also could't find the question you mentioned on Meta community. Can you add the link here? You can also mention the flow id on that question so Meta team can help investigate it

@gafi Thanks for the reply. I found the issue. I was sending an empty string value in the payload. After removing that key, it was working fine.
